# dell original .iso for precision 5520

Tags: boot, 16.04, dell, 17.04

i have precision 5520, but since it came originally with windows dell do not allow me to download linux (ubnutu 16.04) image, i did manage once probably because of security issue that was patched and now i can't get the original image. i'm trying to create ubuntu 17.04 image using dell-recovery --builder and i want to compare images to see the builder did it's job right and make sure i have a backup.

also did anyone here managed to burn the image using dd bs=4M or 'startup disk creator' and actually boot it ? i only managed with their image creation tool on windows.

Comment: All the standard Ubuntu iso files (from http://releases.ubuntu.com/) can be cloned to USB (with `dd` nicknamed 'Data Destroyer' and safer with the **Startup Disk Creator** of Ubuntu 16.04 LTS and newer versions and **Disks** and **mkusb**). But I don't know about the output of 'dell-recovery --builder'. Maybe it needs treatment with `isohybrid` in order to work as cloned. See this link, https://help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb/isohybrid

Comment: for dell laptops you need specific iso cause it's got it's own drivers PLUS all kind of kernel params and setups that it does, i can try to track down all of the changes but it will take me like a week and i might miss some stuff.

DELL iso cannot be burnt using dd, i don't know why , i guess because their image is not coming with gpt partition table with vfat and uefi bootloader. all i need right now is the original .iso as 16.04 doesn't start as is on this laptop.

Comment: Can the Dell iso be burnt to a working boot DVD disk? If this is the case, you could try with `isohybrid`. But do it on a ***copy*** *of the original iso file*, because it will overwrite the file itself. Or is it an image of the installed system, that should be cloned directly to the internal drive?

Comment: guys, 10x for the suggestions, but it's clear, i can flash the image into 2 usb drives, one with dd the other with the flasher from dell (windows program)  and compare the who with bc4 and with a low level tool and fdisk... it still wont help me to get the dell image....

Comment: I am afraid that we do not understand each other. At least I don't understand you, and it seems to me that you are not understanding me. I would guess that the flasher from Dell is an extracting tool, not a cloning tool. Probably the extracting tool will also add something in an active way. It is difficult to know. The result after extraction will be very different from that of cloning (different partition structure, file systems and probably some different files too). I think it will be difficult to compare the two USB drives *with low level tools* and tell what Dell added.

Comment: agreed. this is what i wrote previously, i'm pretty sure that the dell tool:
1. partitions the disk
2. adds gpt partition table and create vfat partition.
3. copy needed files  plus config of the grub bootloader to the vfat partition.
4. run grub-install 
5. create another ext4 fs root partition
6. copy root fs to the new partition.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/65265/discussion-between-sudodus-and-codescriber).

Comment: Did you guys ever resolve this issue? I'm in the EXACT same boat.

Comment: if you have an image, i suggest flashing it using the dell flash tool for windows. it does the trick, if u are on linux you can do what i do and download windows10 images from microsoft and use that in virtualbox\vmmware, works just the same.

If u are missing the file itself i would create  a new image using the dell create image tool, but i've never tried to install it on a fresh PC to tell u if it works.

If it helps, seems like ubuntu 17.10 does work out of the box.